# What scripture or text is the source of this verse on living on others money such as a woman's wealth?

Tags: identification-request, women

> Uttamam  swArjitam vittam madhyamam putrArjitam
>   adhamam bhrAtru jAyAdi stree vittam adhamAdhamam
>
> Meaning: One's own income/wealth is the best to live on, it is moderate to live on son's income, living on brother's income is bad, and it is worst to live on a women's income/wealth.

What text is the source of this verse on living on others money as women's wealth?

Comment: This is a subhaashita and not likely to be in a scripture. Also, hte third part says: 'living on brother's or wife's income is bad'

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Do you know what subhAshita this is from?

Comment: Madhyamam putrarjitam is breaking the chhanda.Pl check

Comment: That's the problem. I heard a pravachan karta state this verse twice so far (he didn't give a source for it) and then on google it shows up in different words/grammer. Hence my question.

Comment: bhavishya purana mentions subsisting off woman's earnings as one of the signs of kali yug. you can clearly see this in action today with the large number of "men" wanting to be 'house-husbands'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This verse is a subhāṣita and not from any texts.

Part of the Mahāsubhāṣitasaṃgraha

> [Sanskrit quote nr. 6464](https://www.wisdomlib.org/sanskrit/quote/mss/subhashita-6464) (Mahā-subhāṣita-saṃgraha)
>
> उत्तमं स्वार्जितं वित्तं मध्यमं पितुरर्जितम् । अधमं भ्रातृवित्तं च
> स्त्रीवित्तमधमाधमम् ॥
>
> uttamaṃ svārjitaṃ vittaṃ madhyamaṃ piturarjitam | adhamaṃ bhrātṛvittaṃ
> ca strīvittamadhamādhamam ||